# Group i consecutive identical character in a string into a list

Tags: python, string, list, implementation

I want the input string to be separated in such a way that all the consecutive identical characters are grouped together in a list.

**Example1:**

**str** : `aabbcccdeddgg`

**output:** `['aa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'd', 'e', 'dd']`

**Desired Output :** `['aa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'd', 'e', 'dd', 'gg']`

**Example2:**

**str** : `helloop`

**output:** `['h', 'e', 'll', 'oo']`

**Desired Output :** `['h','e','ll','oo','p']`

On using the below code:

```
s = input()
li = []
temp_li = []
grp = s[0]
for ch in s[1:]:
    if ch== grp[-1]:
        grp+=ch
    else:
        li.append(grp)

        grp = ch
print(li)
```

*note: Program is not showing output for the last set of identical characters*

**Expected Answers from community:**

- Modification on above program to show the correct output
- or better solution in general

Comment: @user3483203  I believe this question in not duplicate since in this question I have asked for  modification in present code as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
from itertools import groupby
x = "aabbcccdeddgg"
[''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(x)]

>> ['aa', 'bb', 'ccc', 'd', 'e', 'dd', 'gg']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `li.append(grp)` outside the `for` loop to include the last group matched:

```
for ch in s[1:]:
  if ch== grp[-1]:
    grp+=ch
  else:
    li.append(grp)
    grp = ch

li.append(grp) #account for last instance of grp
```

Output (for `s='helloop'`):

```
['l', 'e', 'll', 'oo', 'p']
```